# creating a VPN connection between AWS EC2 Ubuntu server and Ubuntu client

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, amazon-ec2

Setting up VPN server-client connection seems to be tricky. I have a sever on Amazon EC2 and would like to join it to my network at home.

What is the simplest & quickest way to do it? Which software should I use?

Thank you!